# Align text in console in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Basically I want to display a line of numbers in console, and then align them with next line. I found some solutions how to align text in console, but it doesn't say how to do it in loop.

Here's what I tried to do, but after first iteration, it throws an exception:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= blanks.GetLength(1); i++)
{
    Console.Write(String.Format("{" + Convert.ToString(i-1) + ",-10} | ", Convert.ToString(i)));
}
```

Comment: What exception it is throwing?

Comment: try Console.Write(String.Format("{0,-10} | ", Convert.ToString(i)));

Comment: there are good solutions. but i like this
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4449135/7084880)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I align text in columns using Console.WriteLine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449021/how-can-i-align-text-in-columns-using-console-writeline)

Comment: ok, apparently Amit's solution is what I wanted. I thought that first number is a position, but I was wrong. Thank you, good man!